# How to recover accidentally deleted self signed RDP certificate?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

Environment: Windows 2012 on Workgroup setting.

Our Remote Desktop Service was using a self-signed certificate, which was deleted.

Actions taken to delete are:

1. MMC > File > Add/Remove Snap in > Certificates > Computer Account > Local Computer > Finish.
2. Under Console Root hierarchy:
   Console Root > Certificates (Local Computer) > Remote Desktop
3. Certificate selected and deleted.

Is there a way to recover or find that certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate and related private key are gone. You could get the certificate from a client but not the private key. Unless you have a backup you should consider it as lost.

Comment: Where is it stored?

Comment: Personal certificates and key are stored in the personal AppData folder but system and machine certificates and keys are stored in the registry.

Comment: Some of the regsitry keys are HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates 
HKEY_Current_User\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates 
HKEY_Users\User SID\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Services\ServiceName\SystemCertificates 
HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates
HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates 
HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates